# Running a search in gridview Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

```
SELECT personID, name, phoneNumber, age 
FROM dbo.person
WHERE name = ....
```

I have created a database in visual studio and presented it in a gridview. I am currently creating a method where the user can search for a person's name and have the matching rows displayed in gridview.

Visual Studio throws an error when I try to enter the field `userinputTextBox.Text` in the (....) space above.

Has anyone done this before and know a way around it?

Comment: @KiraBorke what exception gets thrown? How do you expect us to determine what the issue is if you don't tell us the exception? We aren't mind readers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include `parameterName` with SELECT statement.

```
SELECT personID, name, phoneNumber, age 
FROM dbo.person
WHERE name=@name
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter the data then better create a view and populate the grid with the data and then filter the grid by passing your query in the textchanged event of the textbox otherwise use sqlreader.